# Getting Azure devops task curl output

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a Azure devops pipeline with a task in it to curl an url, like so:

```
  - script: 'curl -k https://localhost:5005/memorylogger'
    condition: always()
    displayName: 'Get logging'
```

This works (I guess) but does not give me the output of the curl command (should be html)
Instead it shows only this:

[image: taskresult]

The output is from curl because it mentions speeds and percentages..

But if I execute the same curl command on a ubuntu machine, It gives me the html as output.

How do I get the Azure devops task to do that? I scanned all tne curl options but cannot find a option that changes this.

Comment: Do you host application in your pipeline?

Comment: Yes, in a container job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same result when I have not accessible url

```
/usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/6f05796b-7ba7-4780-aeff-b3f9c4602565.sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
```

which was

```
- script: 'curl -k https://www.googled.pl'
  condition: always()
  displayName: 'Get logging'
```

For the correct url I got

```
Generating script.
Script contents:
curl -k https://www.google.pl
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/7274b6ab-c2bd-4cec-ba9d-361fe8bfc443.sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="en-IE"><head><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"><meta content="/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png" itemprop="image"><title>Google</title><script nonce="0B6PcnvTr54_2WONuoOg_w">(function(){var _g={kEI:'D46kZJW1LYCchbIP6tSJCA',kEXPI:'0,1359409,6059,206,4804,2316,383,246,5,1129120,1197697,704,380090,16111,19400,9287,22431,1361,12313,17586,4998,15066,2009,39329,1987,2891,11754,606,63304,13491,230,1014,1,16920,2648,4,1528,2304,42127,13658,4437,22613,6624,7596,1,42154,2,16737,3534,19490,5679,1021,31121,4568,6256,23421,1246,5841,19300,2,7482,27082,8155,6680,701,2,15967,873,6578,13058,6,1921,9779,20640,21819,20198,20233,20206,3370,5007,18960,2305,3098,3030,6111,9705,1804,7734,2738,2885,2455,5199,1826,3570,6690,2172,5252,3534,3027,1635,7948,5892,1146,777,5122,2376,355,3083,7914,7652,3010,560,1533,3,3,9,4113,1271,2041,372,1776,5208545,5994754,2804424,3311,141,795,19735,1,1,346,6910,35,23943540,578,2737886,1305642,16672,2894,6250,19889,3917,2536,151,266,1404037,681643,23078621,2862,1568,897,1842,266,1970,1,1377,1022,421,415,1545,1209,3369,568,2799,98,67,174,623,521,875,198,2434,446,77,537,60,531,544,633,74,1,203,372,370,374,81,595,1148,1505,240,255,483,231,84,1,436,227,249,722,557,4,872,324,324,144,172,516,1,1,793,118,393,450,65,362,169,633,1249,139,9,151,169,354,3,3,2001,759,50,735,525,10,94,8,3,621,139,35,45,460,165,200,1227,156,7,30,393,1831,325,201,74,71,851,10,1833,73,1403,64,190,168,40,2,1318',kBL:'VNBp',kOPI:89978449};(function(){var a;(null==(a=window.google)?0:a.stvsc)?google.kEI=_g.kEI:window.google=_g;}).call(this);})();(function(){google.sn='webhp';google.kHL='en-IE';})();(function(){
var h=this||self;function l(){return void 0!==window.google&&void 0!==window.google.kOPI&&0!==window.google.kOPI?window.google.kOPI:null};var m,n=[];function p(a){for(var b;a&&(!a.getAttribute||!(b=a.getAttribute("eid")));)a=a.parentNode;return b||m}function q(a){for(var b=null;a&&(!a.getAttribute||!(b=a.getAttribute("leid")));)a=a.parentNode;return b}function r(a){/^http:/i.test(a)&&"https:"===window.location.protocol&&(google.ml&&google.ml(Error("a"),!1,{src:a,glmm:1}),a="");return a}
function t(a,b,c,d,k){var e="";-1===b.search("&ei=")&&(e="&ei="+p(d),-1===b.search("&lei=")&&(d=q(d))&&(e+="&lei="+d));d="";var g=-1===b.search("&cshid=")&&"slh"!==a,f=[];f.push(["zx",Date.now().toString()]);h._cshid&&g&&f.push(["cshid",h._cshid]);c=c();null!=c&&f.push(["opi",c.toString()]);for(c=0;c<f.length;c++){if(0===c||0<c)d+="&";d+=f[c][0]+"="+f[c][1]}return"/"+(k||"gen_204")+"?atyp=i&ct="+String(a)+"&cad="+(b+e+d)};m=google.kEI;google.getEI=p;google.getLEI=q;google.ml=function(){return null};google.log=function(a,b,c,d,k,e){e=void 0===e?l:e;c||(c=t(a,b,e,d,k));if(c=r(c)){a=new Image;var g=n.length;n[g]=a;a.onerror=a.onload=a.onabort=function(){delete n[g]};a.src=c}};google.logUrl=function(a,b){b=void 0===b?l:b;return t("",a,b)};}).call(this);(function(){google.y={};google.sy=[];google.x=function(a,b){if(a)var c=a.id;else{do c=Math.random();while(google.y[c])}google.y[c]=[a,b];return!1};google.sx=function(a){google.sy.push(a)};google.lm=[];google.plm=function(a){google.lm.push.apply(google.lm,a)};google.lq=[];google.load=function(a,b,c){google.lq.push([[a],b,c])};google.loadAll=function(a,b){google.lq.push([a,b])};google.bx=!1;google.lx=function(){};}).call(this);google.f={};(function(){
document.documentElement.addEventListener("submit",function(b){var a;if(a=b.target){var c=a.getAttribute("data-submitfalse");a="1"===c||"q"===c&&!a.elements.q.value?!0:!1}else a=!1;a&&(b.preventDefault(),b.stopPropagation())},!0);document.documentElement.addEventListener("click",function(b){var a;a:{for(a=b.target;a&&a!==document.documentElement;a=a.parentElement)if("A"===a.tagName){a="1"===a.getAttribute("data-nohref");break a}a=!1}a&&b.preventDefault()},!0);}).call(this);</script><style>#gbar,#guser{font-size:13px;padding-top:1px !important;}#gbar{height:22px}#guser{padding-bottom:7px !important;text-align:right}.gbh,.gbd{border-top:1px solid #c9d7f1;font-size:1px}.gbh{height:0;position:absolute;top:24px;width:100%}@media all{.gb1{height:22px;margin-right:.5em;vertical-align:top}#gbar{float:left}}a.gb1,a.gb4{text-decoration:underline !important}a.gb1,a.gb4{color:#00c !important}.gbi .gb4{color:#dd8e27 !important}.gbf .gb4{color:#900 !important}
</style><style>body,td,a,p,.h{font-family:arial,sans-serif}body{margin:0;overflow-y:scroll}#gog{padding:3px 8px 0}td{line-height:.8em}.gac_m td{line-height:17px}form{margin-bottom:20px}.h{color:#1967d2}em{font-weight:bold;font-style:normal}.lst{height:25px;width:496px}.gsfi,.lst{font:18px arial,sans-serif}.gsfs{font:17px arial,sans-serif}.ds{display:inline-box;display:inline-block;margin:3px 0 4px;margin-left:4px}input{font-family:inherit}body{background:#fff;color:#000}a{color:#681da8;text-decoration:none}a:hover,a:active{text-decoration:underline}.fl a{color:#1967d2}a:visited{color:#681da8}.sblc{padding-top:5px}.sblc a{display:block;margin:2px 0;margin-left:13px;font-size:11px}.lsbb{background:#f8f9fa;border:solid 1px;border-color:#dadce0 #70757a #70757a #dadce0;height:30px}.lsbb{display:block}#WqQANb a{display:inline-block;margin:0 12px}.lsb{background:url(/images/nav_logo229.png) 0 -261px repeat-x;color:#000;border:none;cursor:pointer;height:30px;margin:0;outline:0;font:15px arial,sans-serif;vertical-align:top}.lsb:active{background:#dadce0}.lst:focus{outline:none}</style><script nonce="0B6PcnvTr54_2WONuoOg_w">(function(){window.google.erd={jsr:1,bv:1823,de:true};
var l=this||self;var m,n=null!=(m=l.mei)?m:1,p,q=null!=(p=l.sdo)?p:!0,r=0,t,u=google.erd,v=u.jsr;google.ml=function(a,b,d,e,f){f=void 0===f?2:f;b&&(t=a&&a.message);if(google.dl)return google.dl(a,f,d),null;if(0>v){window.console&&console.error(a,d);if(-2===v)throw a;b=!1}else b=!a||!a.message||"Error loading script"===a.message||r>=n&&!e?!1:!0;if(!b)return null;r++;d=d||{};b=encodeURIComponent;var c="/gen_204?atyp=i&ei="+b(google.kEI);google.kEXPI&&(c+="&jexpid="+b(google.kEXPI));c+="&srcpg="+b(google.sn)+"&jsr="+b(u.jsr)+"&bver="+b(u.bv);var g=a.lineNumber;void 0!==g&&(c+="&line="+g);var h=
a.fileName;h&&(0<h.indexOf("-extension:/")&&(f=3),c+="&script="+b(h),g&&h===window.location.href&&(g=document.documentElement.outerHTML.split("\n")[g],c+="&cad="+b(g?g.substring(0,300):"No script found.")));c+="&jsel="+f;for(var k in d)c+="&",c+=b(k),c+="=",c+=b(d[k]);c=c+"&emsg="+b(a.name+": "+a.message);c=c+"&jsst="+b(a.stack||"N/A");12288<=c.length&&(c=c.substr(0,12288));a=c;e||google.log(0,"",a);return a};window.onerror=function(a,b,d,e,f){if(t!==a){a=f instanceof Error?f:Error(a);void 0===d||"lineNumber"in a||(a.lineNumber=d);void 0===b||"fileName"in a||(a.fileName=b);b=void 0;if(a.stack&&(-1!==a.stack.indexOf("?xjs=s0")||a.stack.indexOf("&xjs=s0"))){b=document.querySelectorAll("script[src*=\\/xjs\\/_\\/js\\/]");for(e=d=0;e<b.length;e++)console.log(b[e].async),d+=b[e].async?1:0;var c=f=e=-1,g=-1,h=-1;if(performance&&google.xjsu){e=0;f=google.timers.load.t.xjsee?1:0;g=c=0;h=performance.getEntriesByType("resource");for(var k=0;k<h.length;k++)h[k].name===google.xjsu&&(e=1),-1!==h[k].name.indexOf("/xjs/_/js/")&&(c+=1,g+="script"===h[k].initiatorType?1:0);h=c-g}b={cad:"pl_"+e+".pe_"+f+".asc_"+d+".tsc_"+b.length+".fasc_"+(b.length-d)+".lxc_"+c+".lsx_"+g+".lnsx_"+h}}google.ml(a,!1,b,!1,"SyntaxError"===a.name||"SyntaxError"===a.message.substring(0,11)||-1!==a.message.indexOf("Script error")?3:0)}t=null;q&&r>=n&&(window.onerror=null)};})();</script></head><body bgcolor="#fff"><script nonce="0B6PcnvTr54_2WONuoOg_w">(function(){var src='/images/nav_logo229.png';var iesg=false;document.body.onload = function(){window.n && window.n();if (document.images){new Image().src=src;}
if (!iesg){document.f&&document.f.q.focus();document.gbqf&&document.gbqf.q.focus();}
}
})();</script><div id="mngb"><div id=gbar><nobr><b class=gb1>Search</b> <a class=gb1 href="https://www.google.pl/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi">Images</a> <a class=gb1 href="https://maps.google.ie/maps?hl=en&tab=wl">Maps</a> <a class=gb1 href="https://play.google.com/?hl=en&tab=w8">Play</a> <a class=gb1 href="https://www.youtube.com/?tab=w1">YouTube</a> <a class=gb1 href="https://news.google.com/?tab=wn">News</a> <a class=gb1 href="https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm">Gmail</a> <a class=gb1 href="https://drive.google.com/?tab=wo">Drive</a> <a class=gb1 style="text-decoration:none" href="https://www.google.ie/intl/en/about/products?tab=wh"><u>More</u> &raquo;</a></nobr></div><div id=guser width=100%><nobr><span id=gbn class=gbi></span><span id=gbf class=gbf></span><span id=gbe></span><a href="http://www.google.ie/history/optout?hl=en" class=gb4>Web History</a> | <a  href="/preferences?hl=en" class=gb4>Settings</a> | <a target=_top id=gb_70 href="https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&passive=true&continue=https://www.google.pl/&ec=GAZAAQ" class=gb4>Sign in</a></nobr></div><div class=gbh style=left:0></div><div class=gbh style=right:0></div></div><center><br clear="all" id="lgpd"><div id="lga"><img alt="Google" height="92" src="/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_white_background_color_272x92dp.png" style="padding:28px 0 14px" width="272" id="hplogo"><br><br></div><form action="/search" name="f"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr valign="top"><td width="25%">&nbsp;</td><td align="center" nowrap=""><input name="ie" value="ISO-8859-2" type="hidden"><input value="en-IE" name="hl" type="hidden"><input name="source" type="hidden" value="hp"><input name="biw" type="hidden"><input name="bih" type="hidden"><div class="ds" style="height:32px;margin:4px 0"><input class="lst" style="margin:0;padding:5px 8px 0 6px;vertical-align:top;color:#000" autocomplete="off" value="" title="Google Search" maxlength="2048" name="q" size="57"></div><br style="line-height:0"><span class="ds"><span class="lsbb"><input class="lsb" value="Google Search" name="btnG" type="submit"></span></span><span class="ds"><span class="lsbb"><input class="lsb" id="tsuid_1" value="I'm Feeling Lucky" name="btnI" type="submit"><script nonce="0B6PcnvTr54_2WONuoOg_w">(function(){var id='tsuid_1';document.getElementById(id).onclick = function(){if (this.form.q.value){this.checked = 1;if (this.form.iflsig)this.form.iflsig.disabled = false;}
else top.location='/doodles/';};})();</script><input value="AD69kcEAAAAAZKScH7kdbvSrib3SkeVDeA0VGhUSJ_T-" name="iflsig" type="hidden"></span></span></td><td class="fl sblc" align="left" nowrap="" width="25%"><a href="/advanced_search?hl=en-IE&amp;authuser=0">Advanced search</a></td></tr></table><input id="gbv" name="gbv" type="hidden" value="1"><script nonce="0B6PcnvTr54_2WONuoOg_w">(function(){var a,b="1";if(document&&document.getElementById)if("undefined"!=typeof XMLHttpRequest)b="2";else if("undefined"!=typeof ActiveXObject){var c,d,e=["MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0","MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0","MSXML2.XMLHTTP","Microsoft.XMLHTTP"];for(c=0;d=e[c++];)try{new ActiveXObject(d),b="2"}catch(h){}}a=b;if("2"==a&&-1==location.search.indexOf("&gbv=2")){var f=google.gbvu,g=document.getElementById("gbv");g&&(g.value=a);f&&window.setTimeout(function(){location.href=f},0)};}).call(this);</script></form><div id="gac_scont"></div><div style="font-size:83%;min-height:3.5em"><br><div id="gws-output-pages-elements-homepage_additional_languages__als"><style>#gws-output-pages-elements-homepage_additional_languages__als{font-size:small;margin-bottom:24px}#SIvCob{color:#3c4043;display:inline-block;line-height:28px;}#SIvCob a{padding:0 3px;}.H6sW5{display:inline-block;margin:0 2px;white-space:nowrap}.z4hgWe{display:inline-block;margin:0 2px}</style><div id="SIvCob">Google offered in:  <a href="https://www.google.pl/setprefs?sig=0_G-Eic7_dSsU5OgOP03PzoGD5SF4%3D&amp;hl=pl&amp;source=homepage&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=0ahUKEwjV-L7F_vX_AhUATkEAHWpqAgEQ2ZgBCAU">polski</a>    <a href="https://www.google.pl/setprefs?sig=0_G-Eic7_dSsU5OgOP03PzoGD5SF4%3D&amp;hl=ga&amp;source=homepage&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=0ahUKEwjV-L7F_vX_AhUATkEAHWpqAgEQ2ZgBCAY">Gaeilge</a>  </div></div></div><span id="footer"><div style="font-size:10pt"><div style="margin:19px auto;text-align:center" id="WqQANb"><a href="/intl/en/ads/">Advertising</a><a href="http://www.google.ie/intl/en/services/">Business Solutions</a><a href="/intl/en/about.html">About Google</a><a href="https://www.google.pl/setprefdomain?prefdom=US&amp;sig=K_Of7HrGSx1YBmHQPTN1ET7haNCk4%3D" id="fehl">Google.com</a></div></div><p style="font-size:8pt;color:#70757a">&copy; 2023 - <a href="/intl/en/policies/privacy/">Privacy</a> - <a href="/intl/en/policies/terms/">Terms</a></p></span></center><script nonce="0B6PcnvTr54_2WONuoOg_w">(function(){window.google.cdo={height:757,width:1440};(function(){var a=window.innerWidth,b=window.innerHeight;if(!a||!b){var c=window.document,d="CSS1Compat"==c.compatMode?c.documentElement:c.body;a=d.clientWidth;b=d.clientHeight}
if(a&&b&&(a!=google.cdo.width||b!=google.cdo.height)){var e=google,f=e.log,g="/client_204?&atyp=i&biw="+a+"&bih="+b+"&ei="+google.kEI,h="",k=[],l=void 0!==window.google&&void 0!==window.google.kOPI&&0!==window.google.kOPI?window.google.kOPI:null;null!=l&&k.push(["opi",l.toString()]);for(var m=0;m<k.length;m++){if(0===m||0<m)h+="&";h+=k[m][0]+"="+k[m][1]}f.call(e,"","",g+h)};}).call(this);})();</script> <script nonce="0B6PcnvTr54_2WONuoOg_w">(function(){google.xjs={ck:'xjs.hp.KmgsEx1Za9c.L.X.O',cs:'ACT90oGvn2GYaC76O55g_mrMY5MEji5J9Q',csss:'ACT90oFTid_mitzF78rVvgdfjZbEZmvZBA',excm:[],sepcss:false};})();</script>    <script nonce="0B6PcnvTr54_2WONuoOg_w">(function(){var u='/xjs/_/js/k\x3dxjs.hp.en.9QlM0Up86x4.O/am\x3dAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAANAJAFAAwAI/d\x3d1/ed\x3d1/rs\x3dACT90oG6sriSlbnpJf5RZ94dYrXEj-CeTw/m\x3dsb_he,d,cEt90b,SNUn3,qddgKe,sTsDMc,dtl0hd,eHDfl';var amd=0;
var e=this||self,f=function(c){return c};var g;var k=function(c){this.g=c};k.prototype.toString=function(){return this.g+""};var m={};
function q(){var c=u,n=function(){};google.lx=google.stvsc?n:function(){google.timers&&google.timers.load&&google.tick&&google.tick("load","xjsls");var a=document;var b="SCRIPT";"application/xhtml+xml"===a.contentType&&(b=b.toLowerCase());b=a.createElement(b);a=null===c?"null":void 0===c?"undefined":c;if(void 0===g){var d=null;var l=e.trustedTypes;if(l&&l.createPolicy){try{d=l.createPolicy("goog#html",{createHTML:f,createScript:f,createScriptURL:f})}catch(r){e.console&&e.console.error(r.message)}g=
d}else g=d}a=(d=g)?d.createScriptURL(a):a;a=new k(a,m);b.src=a instanceof k&&a.constructor===k?a.g:"type_error:TrustedResourceUrl";var h,p;(h=(a=null==(p=(h=(b.ownerDocument&&b.ownerDocument.defaultView||window).document).querySelector)?void 0:p.call(h,"script[nonce]"))?a.nonce||a.getAttribute("nonce")||"":"")&&b.setAttribute("nonce",h);document.body.appendChild(b);google.psa=!0;google.lx=n};google.bx||google.lx()};google.xjsu=u;e._F_jsUrl=u;setTimeout(function(){0<amd?google.caft(function(){return q()},amd):q()},0);})();window._ = window._ || {};window._DumpException = _._DumpException = function(e){throw e;};window._s = window._s || {};_s._DumpException = _._DumpException;window._qs = window._qs || {};_qs._DumpException = _._DumpException;function _F_installCss(c){}
(function(){google.jl={blt:'none',chnk:0,dw:false,dwu:true,emtn:0,end:0,ico:false,ikb:0,ine:false,injs:'none',injt:0,injth:0,injv2:false,lls:'default',pdt:0,rep:0,snet:true,strt:0,ubm:false,uwp:true};})();(function(){var pmc='{\x22d\x22:{},\x22sb_he\x22:{\x22agen\x22:true,\x22cgen\x22:true,\x22client\x22:\x22heirloom-hp\x22,\x22dh\x22:true,\x22ds\x22:\x22\x22,\x22fl\x22:true,\x22host\x22:\x22google.pl\x22,\x22jsonp\x22:true,\x22lm\x22:true,\x22msgs\x22:{\x22cibl\x22:\x22Clear Search\x22,\x22dym\x22:\x22Did you mean:\x22,\x22lcky\x22:\x22I\\u0026#39;m Feeling Lucky\x22,\x22lml\x22:\x22Learn more\x22,\x22psrc\x22:\x22This search was removed from your \\u003Ca href\x3d\\\x22/history\\\x22\\u003EWeb History\\u003C/a\\u003E\x22,\x22psrl\x22:\x22Remove\x22,\x22sbit\x22:\x22Search by image\x22,\x22srch\x22:\x22Google Search\x22},\x22ovr\x22:{},\x22pq\x22:\x22\x22,\x22rfs\x22:[],\x22sbas\x22:\x220 3px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.08)\x22,\x22stok\x22:\x22Ev9e7o2tcNjjWB_zerIUn9m8bmI\x22}}';google.pmc=JSON.parse(pmc);})();(function(){
var b=function(a){var c=0;return function(){return c<a.length?{done:!1,value:a[c++]}:{done:!0}}},e=this||self;var g,h;a:{for(var k=["CLOSURE_FLAGS"],l=e,n=0;n<k.length;n++)if(l=l[k[n]],null==l){h=null;break a}h=l}var p=h&&h[610401301];g=null!=p?p:!1;var q,r=e.navigator;q=r?r.userAgentData||null:null;function t(a){return g?q?q.brands.some(function(c){return(c=c.brand)&&-1!=c.indexOf(a)}):!1:!1}function u(a){var c;a:{if(c=e.navigator)if(c=c.userAgent)break a;c=""}return-1!=c.indexOf(a)};function v(){return g?!!q&&0<q.brands.length:!1}function w(){return u("Safari")&&!(x()||(v()?0:u("Coast"))||(v()?0:u("Opera"))||(v()?0:u("Edge"))||(v()?t("Microsoft Edge"):u("Edg/"))||(v()?t("Opera"):u("OPR"))||u("Firefox")||u("FxiOS")||u("Silk")||u("Android"))}function x(){return v()?t("Chromium"):(u("Chrome")||u("CriOS"))&&!(v()?0:u("Edge"))||u("Silk")}function y(){return u("Android")&&!(x()||u("Firefox")||u("FxiOS")||(v()?0:u("Opera"))||u("Silk"))};var z=v()?!1:u("Trident")||u("MSIE");y();x();w();var A=!z&&!w(),D=function(a){if(/-[a-z]/.test("ved"))return null;if(A&&a.dataset){if(y()&&!("ved"in a.dataset))return null;a=a.dataset.ved;return void 0===a?null:a}return a.getAttribute("data-"+"ved".replace(/([A-Z])/g,"-$1").toLowerCase())};var E=[],F=null;function G(a){a=a.target;var c=performance.now(),f=[],H=f.concat,d=E;if(!(d instanceof Array)){var m="undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.iterator&&d[Symbol.iterator];if(m)d=m.call(d);else if("number"==typeof d.length)d={next:b(d)};else throw Error("a`"+String(d));for(var B=[];!(m=d.next()).done;)B.push(m.value);d=B}E=H.call(f,d,[c]);if(a&&a instanceof HTMLElement)if(a===F){if(c=4<=E.length)c=5>(E[E.length-1]-E[E.length-4])/1E3;if(c){c=google.getEI(a);a.hasAttribute("data-ved")?f=a?D(a)||"":"":f=(f=
a.closest("[data-ved]"))?D(f)||"":"";f=f||"";if(a.hasAttribute("jsname"))a=a.getAttribute("jsname");else{var C;a=null==(C=a.closest("[jsname]"))?void 0:C.getAttribute("jsname")}google.log("rcm","&ei="+c+"&ved="+f+"&jsname="+(a||""))}}else F=a,E=[c]}window.document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){document.body.addEventListener("click",G)});}).call(this);</script></body></html>
100 18413    0 18413    0     0   179k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  179k
Finishing: Get logging
```

Are you sure you host your application when running the pipeline?

Comment: Turns out that my url was returning a 500. But curl does not show this.. I build a C# app to run instead of curl to find this out.